# css configuration in webpack not detecting class styles but detects element styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am using to react with webpack and babel. I have webpack configuration as follows. When I write CSS into for elements like div, ul, li etc it is detected in my `App.js` but when I try to write class based CSS it is not detected on the page.

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, '..', '/src/index.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                minimize: true,
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5].css',
                sourcemaps: true,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourcemaps: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                minimize: true,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourcemaps: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

#### index.css

```
.test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em; 
  list-style: none;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../index.css';


const App = () => (
  <div>
     <h1>Hello Adeva!!</h1>
     <ul className="test">
        <li>Romans</li>
        <li>Corinthians</li>
        <li>Thessalonians</li>
        <li>Ephesians</li>
        <li>Phillipians</li>
        <li>Colossians</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
)

export default App;
```

My react version is 16.8.1, webpack is 4.29.3. Please guide me as this webpack configuration thing is very getting confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured webpack to use css modules by adding `modules: true` in your css-loader config. To use css modules you have to access the styles as javascript object, like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../index.css';


const App = () => (
  <div>
     <h1>Hello Adeva!!</h1>
     <ul className={styles.test}>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mohamed it works but I read that from webpack v4 ExtractTextPlugin should not be used. Is that so?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know

Answer (score -3):

why complicate things just do

```
<ul class="test">
```

Plain css and html

Comment: Please add explanation how this will work in the context of this question, not general HTML.